# Movie in which person turns into monster by mask with tubes

Tags: story-identification

Some time ago I watched a movie, of which one scene never left my mind.
In that scene there was a room full of shelves and tubes and jars (some kind of laboratorium), with a man in it.

Someone else enters the room and forces him to lie down. Then he (the person who just entered) puts a mask on the first man's face with a lot of tubes attached to it.
All kinds of fluids then enter the man's body and he starts twitching uncontrollably.
However, he isn't killed by it (which also wasn't the purpose), but he turns into a monster, ripping everything off him and smashing everything in the room to smithereens.

I think the movie was released in the late 20th or early 21th century.

Does anyone know which movie this could be?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av0Y4YVAUs8) probably also isn't it, so I'll just post it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: If it really *is* Batman & Robin, for your safety and for the safety of those around you, abandon your goal of rewatching the movie. Nothing good will come of it.

Comment: Good actors, bad movie.

Comment: (meta 'discussion' about this question here: [Which answer should I choose? - SF&F Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3671/24993))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was it Bane's transformation in [*Batman & Robin* (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118688/)?

Bane was strapped down, is injected with "super soldier serum", twitches, and breaks free, destroying things.

Answer (score 10):

Could it have been **Batman and Robin**? I'd consider it unlikely, simply due to them being so popular and their presence in the movie unlikely to be forgotten, but the scene you described sounds really reminiscent to **Bane's transformation** in that movie:

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *[Riese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riese:_Kingdom_Falling)* from SyFy?

> The series is about a traveller named Riese, who flees across the wartorn lands of Eleysia with her wolf, Fenrir. Hunted by a terrifying religious group, The Sect, Riese must evade the assassins that have been sent to kill her and discover their true objective.

[Herrick](https://riese-kingdom-falling.fandom.com/wiki/Herrick), a major antagonist, is always seen in a mask:
[image: Image of Herrick in his mask]

> Masked and nearly inhuman, Herrick is a Senior Magister in The Sect. His charge is to seek out and punish heretics. Only a select few know his former identity or his reasons for joining the Sect. Even fewer have seen his true face, which is covered by a horrifying mask worn by the purest of magisters. His rank amongst the Sect is high, which is evident by the relics he has affixed to his body. Herrick has been ordered by Empress Amara to hunt Riese. He deigns to follow Amara's orders, appearing to work in congress with her, though there are signs he has motives of his own. Vicious and without conscience, he will stop at nothing to ensure his objective is complete.

Comment: Does the scene I described occur in the series? (and if yes, in which episode?)

Comment: nevermind, I watched half of the episodes, and I don't think this is it. The movie I saw was definitely released before 2009.

Comment: There's a cliffhanger where he's first modified, wrecks the lab and kills the doctor(s), but I think the Bane answer is much closer to what you're looking for!

Comment: Even if this is the wrong answer, it doesn't hurt to have more details. It may help someone else find it.